# PostGIS rotating a line string to be vertical when viewed on screen

Tags: postgis, azimuth

I'm building a Node.js application that will display Google Maps satellite images of golf course holes. I have 2 GPS points I'm pulling from a PostgreSQL database and I need to be able to take any image and align it to display vertically.

How do I calculate the degrees I need to rotate the image so that it displays vertically

With the example image below I've calculate the degrees between the 2 points using

```
degrees(ST_Azimuth( ST_MakePoint(c1.latitude, c1.longitude), ST_MakePoint(c2.latitude, c2.longitude)))
```

where c1 is the starting point and c2 is the end point. This gives me a result of 7.564173260256835 but I'm not sure what else I need to do with that value to rotate the image to be vertical like the one below where I needed a 45deg rotation

[image: original image]

[image]

Comment: You can't use `ST_Azimuth` that way. It's designed for Cartesian calculation, which doesn't work correctly on angular coordinate data.  You need to cast the ST_MakePoint results to `geography` for geodesic angles to be calculated (`degrees(ST_Azimuth( ST_MakePoint(c1.latitude, c1.longitude)::geography, ST_MakePoint(c2.latitude, c2.longitude)::geography))`). Whatever code that handles the image rotation can deal with plot rotation.

Comment: The result from that with the cast is 1.2684457763873518 which still doesnt tell me how to rotate that image. Is there a function that can tell me how many degrees to rotate a line string so its pointing north?

Comment: All (most) GEOS/OGC related functions expect **`X, Y` order (`Lon, Lat`)** of coordinates passed in as arguments!

Comment: Thank you both this has solved my problem. Getting the expected result to pass into the image manipulation code.